# VS2019 compiles TS differently on save or on build, how can i fix this?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript

When i have a "simple" typescript file, when i save the file i want it to be compiled in to a js file.

This is my ts file.

```
declare var axios
declare var Vue

export interface IProduct {
    Id: number;
    Code: string;
    Description: string;
    Ean: string;
}

var vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        products: []
    },
    mounted () {
        this.getProductsList()
    },
    methods: {
        getProductsList: function() {
            axios
                .get('/Umbraco/Api/Products/List')
                .then(response => (this.products = response.data))
        }
    }
});
```

now i have a strange phenomenen, when i BUILD the project, this is the file that is generated (CTRL + ALT + B)

```
var vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        products: []
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.getProductsList();
    },
    methods: {
        getProductsList: function () {
            var _this = this;
            axios
                .get('/Umbraco/Api/Products/List')
                .then(function (response) { return (_this.products = response.data); });
        }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=ProductList.js.map
```

but when i SAVE the file, it gets compiled differently.

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        products: []
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.getProductsList();
    },
    methods: {
        getProductsList: function () {
            var _this = this;
            axios
                .get('/Umbraco/Api/Products/List')
                .then(function (response) { return (_this.products = response.data); });
        }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=ProductList.js.map
```

how does it come?

i am using a tsconfig.json configuration file with these settings

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "strict": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "ESNext",    
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

I have no idea why the change? and it is breaking the output when i save the file.
i don't want it to generate Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true }); this line

Comment: Does it help if you set `module` to `none`?

as a side note, i would advice against using VS for typescript.

Comment: if i set module to none, i cant use export to use the interface IProduct so it is not an option, i am looking for a good way of working, i don't want to run 20 toolchains in order to build and debug my projects. if you have a good way of working, feel free to share it with me.

Comment: my prefferred way of working with typescript is with modules and a bundler, and there you can use `import` and `export`. But it seems to me that you don't use modules, and so `export` doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: e.g. I have `first.ts` and `second.ts`, these are not modules, so there is no `export` or `import` in them. `first.ts` has contains `interface A {}`, and the `second.ts` can reference it without any problem, without `export` or `declare`. All you need is to compile them with `tsc ./first.ts ./second.ts`. But it doesn't work if you only want to compile the second file. I guess when you compile on save, it only includes the current file in the compilation.

Comment: but you can also use triple-slash reference like `///  <reference path="./first.ts" />` (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) in `second.ts`, and now types are visible even if you only compile one file with `tsc ./second.ts`